# How to read dynamically created radio buttons' value in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

I am creating some radio buttons dynamically, in a user control, based on readings from a config file. Config key "str_Regions" can contain any number of comma separated values. Following is the code:

```
<ul class="form_items">
        <%
            int i=1;
            string displayText = String.Empty;
            foreach (var region in Configuration.ConfigString("str_Regions").Split(','))
            {
                string Radio = "Radio" + (i++).ToString();
                displayText = displayText + "<li><input type=\"radio\" id=" + Radio + " name=\"region\" value=" + region +
                              " runat=\"server\">" + region + "</input></li>";
            }
         %>
        <%=displayText%>
        </ul>
```

I don't think a radio button object is being created this way. When I do "`if(Radio1.Checked)`" from code behind, I get null reference exception.

So, I want to check, through user-control's code behind, which of the radio buttons is selected and do some action by reading selected button's value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Stringbuilder**

Use stringbuilder to create long strings. (performance improvement)

**Radio buttons**

If you are using Jquery:

*Code*

`$('form_items input[type="radio"]').each(function(index, currentObject)
    {
        if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
        {
            i++;
        }
    });`

where 'i++' is placed, u can add it too an aray or something where u take the value of the currentObject

Comment: I want to read the values of radio button from c# code of user control, not jQuery or java-script.